# A holomorphic function as a product of derivatives of two other holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be a domain in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ and $f : D \longrightarrow \mathbb{C} $ a holomorphic function. Does there exist a holomorphic function $F$ on $D$ such that  $F^{\prime} = f$ on $D$. If such $F$ exists, we call it a primitive of $f$.

We know that existence of a primitive is not always guaranteed. For instance, if $D = \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ and $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$, then there is no primitive of $\frac{1}{z}$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$.

Now, the question is the following:

**Do there alwasys exist holomorphic functions $F, G$ on $D$ such that $f = F^{\prime}G^{\prime}$?**

If we take the same example as above, $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$, and set $F(z) =\frac{z^2}{2}$,  $G(z) =-\frac{1}{z}$, then we see that $f(z) = \frac{1}{z} =  F^{\prime}(z)G^{\prime}(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$.

I was trying to do a similar kind of trick for $f(z) = \frac{z - 1}{z}$, but did not succeed. So I am hoping to get a negative answer to the question above, though I could not conclude anything.

Comment: Use $(z-1)/z^3, z^2$

Comment: $(z-1)/z^3$ is the derivative of $-1/z+1/(2z^2)$ and obviously $z^2$ is a derivative; in general I see no reason for this not to hold at least on nice domains like the punctured plane or an annulus